# How does Proxifier resolve hostnames through proxy?

Tags: tcp, proxy, dns, udp

What technique is Proxifier using to resolve hostnames through proxy? All other solutions I've found on the Internet offers DNS through socks just like what Badvpn/Tun2Socks does. But Proxifier can work even through a http proxy and the only thing you need is that your proxy server support DNS (Squid for example). Their explanation is very brief saying "[Proxifier has to assign placeholder (fake) IP addresses](http://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/dns.htm)". But what that mean exactly?

Note: As you know DNS queries are UDP by default and can't be forwarded through http proxy naturally. Browsers are another examples which do name resolution through proxy when are set to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. [Redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) has implemented this indeed, as it says:

> Redsocks includes `dnstc' that is fake and really dumb DNS server that
>   returns "truncated answer" to every query via UDP. RFC-compliant
>   resolver should repeat same query via TCP in this case - so the
>   request can be redirected using usual redsocks facilities.

Comment: So there is no api to channel the dns queries through a proxy from the OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning fake IP in response to DNS request is different from returning truncated DNS answer.

Here's the related RFC about assigning fake IPs in response to DNS request in order to get the domain name and pass it to the remote proxy server afterward: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3089